# Cocos2d - Launch the App only when there is WiFi

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Last time I had a question here [Cocos2d - purgeIdleCellConnections Error: App is crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451250/cocos2d-purgeidlecellconnections-error-app-is-crashing#comment20179281_14451250) but did not get any answer.
Now, I am trying to implement to run my App only when there is a WiFi connection. This is a Cocos2d game project, so is there any example to check the WiFi connection after the App is launched? Or, any link for the guidance?

Comment: there's a good chance such an app won't get approved by Apple. You need to offer some kind of (limited) offline mode at the least.

Comment: Thanks Steffen for your reply. Would you please recommend me the best json parser framework? I need to implement it in cocos2d, I am using Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6.